# How to print Office365 Verbose Error Message

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to create a user in O365 Graph AD using ReST endpoint. For some of the users we are getting the following error message 
 
     *Error with response code 400 : {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"An error occurred while processing the write request."},"values":null}}*

To get verbose logs we tried setting the "Content-Type"  to application/json;odata=verbose but still we are not able to see the full error. Can someone help in fixing this error or help in printing the verbose logs.